# Forcing context switch in Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, context-switch

Is there a way to force a context switch in C++ to a specific thread, assuming I have the thread handle or thread ID?

Comment: If an application could force a certain thread to execute, that would eventually mean that a higher-priority process or thread would get starved, rendering any kind of process priorities or scheduler fairness algorithm moot. Also, what if the thread you were forcing to run were not ready to run? If it's blocked on a read, and wakes up, it's going to assume that there's something to read.

Comment: What's the motivation behind the question?

Comment: I need the non-running thread to take control of a critical section. :)

Comment: Ok, never mind, I'll just busy loop until this thread kicks in :)

Comment: @ldov you should just release the critical section and the other thread will take control when it runs again. Busy loop doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't be able to **force** operating system to run the thread you want. You can use `yield` to force a context switch though...

`yield` in Win32 API is function [`SwitchToThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If there is no other thread available for running, then a **ZERO** value will be returned and current thread will keep running anyway.

Comment: Actually this is not true. SwitchToThread does not guarantee a context switch. If there are no threads eligible to run on this processor then this thread will continue.

Comment: but it can be ANY thread running that processor, not just in my process, right?

Comment: @Idov: right. It can be ANY thread running, not just your process. That's an OS limitation. OS is in full control of process/thread scheduling.

Comment: @David Hefferman: true. In the extremely unlikely case that there is absolutely no other thread in that process or in other process, then I guess it will keep the current thread running.

Comment: Well, it's very common for there to be no ready threads waiting to run. That happens often, when there are more logical cores than ready to run, waiting threads.

Comment: @David: you mean in a process? Or in the whole operating system?

Comment: @Pablo No, in the whole OS. Right now as I type this, every time I pause to think the CPU utilisation drops to 0% because there is no thread ready to run.  All threads in the system are blocking.

Answer (score 4):

You can only encourage the Windows thread scheduler to pick a certain thread, you can't force it.  You do so first by making the thread block on a synchronization object and signaling it.  Secondary by bumping up its priority.

Explicit context switching is supported, you'll have to use fibers.  Review SwitchToFiber().  A fiber is not a thread by a long shot, it is similar to a co-routine of old.  Fibers' heyday has come and gone, they are not competitive with threads anymore.  They have very crappy cpu cache locality and cannot take advantage of multiple cores.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to force a particular thread to run is by using process/thread affinity, but I can't imagine ever having a problem for which this was a reasonable solution.

The only way to force a context switch is to force a thread onto a different processor using affinity.

In other words, what you are trying to do isn't really viable.

Calling [`SwitchToThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will result in a context switch if there is another thread ready to run that are eligible to run on this processor.  The documentation states it as follows:

> If calling the SwitchToThread function
>   causes the operating system to switch
>   execution to another thread, the
>   return value is nonzero.
>
> If there are no other threads ready to
>   execute, the operating system does not
>   switch execution to another thread,
>   and the return value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily bump the priority of the other thread, while looping with `Sleep(0)` calls: this passes control to other threads. Suppose that the other thread has increased a `lock` variable and you need to wait until it becomes zero again:

```
// Wait until other thread releases lock
SetThreadPriority(otherThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHER);
while (InterlockedRead(&lock) != 0)
  Sleep(0);
SetThreadPriority(otherThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: What you state here is incorrect. From the documentation of `Sleep()`: A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution.

Comment: No it doesn't. If there isn't another thread ready to run the `Sleep(0)` is effectively a no-op.

Comment: Sure, but if there isn't another thread ready to run, nothing else will work either.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the book Concurrent Programming for Windows.  The scheduler seems to do a few things worth noting.

Sleep(0) only yields to higher priority threads (or possibly others at the same priority).  This means you cannot fix priority inversion situations with just a Sleep(0), where other lower priority threads need to run.  You must use SwitchToThread, Sleep a non-zero duration, or fully block on some kernel HANDLE.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two synchronization objects (such as two [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964766(v=vs.85).aspx)) and use the API [SignalObjectAndWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686293(v=vs.85).aspx).

If the `hObjectToWaitOn` is non-signaled and your other thread is waiting on the `hObjectToSignal`, the OS can *theoretically* perform quick context switch inside this API, before end of time slice.

And if you want the current thread to automatically resume, simply inform a small value (such as 50 or 100) on the `dwMilliseconds`.